# Error when uploading archive to App Store: The bundle is invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. My info.plist says 1.2 and the app store is ready for a 1.2.

[image: error]

[image: 1.2]

[image: app store]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunesConnect interprets each sequence of digits in the version as an independent integer, it doesn't look at the number as a decimal.

- 1.15 is version 1, subversion 15
- 1.2 is version 1, subversion 2

2 is less than 15, so you cannot release 1.2 after you have released 1.15 (which perhaps you intended to be 1.1.5)

You can release 1.20 since 20 is greater than 15.

Comment: Oh Apple. Thank you! Ill accept the answer when it lets me